# Rails: getting a token from session or database 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth, koala

I followed along with Ryan Bates' authenticating with Facebook Railscast http://media.railscasts.com/assets/episodes/videos/360-facebook-authentication.ogv in which he uses `gem 'omniauth-facebook'` to authenticate with Facebook. At the end of the Railscast, he introduces Koala, which allows you to interact with the open graph api. Ryan gives instructions to pass the oath token as a parameter into this

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(your_oauth_token)
```

I'm having trouble getting this to work because I'm not sure where to get the oath token from. Let me explain....

In the sessions_controller.rb, we have this

```
 def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id

    redirect_to root_url

  end
```

which saves the omniauth information to the database in the User model

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.name = auth.info.name
    user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
    user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
    user.save!
  end
```

so I'm guessing I need the `user.oath_token` passed into

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(your_oauth_token)
```

but I can't get it to work.

Can you please imagine that I have a Main controller and an index action.

```
Main_controller.rb
   def index
       @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(how do I get the oauth token in here?)
   end
```

**Question**
How would I get the oath token (from either the session or the database) into the index method of the main controller?

For example, using the helper method in application_controller.rb

```
  def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]

   end
  helper_method :current_user
```

I tried to do this in main_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(current_user.oauth_token)
    @graph_data = @graph.get_object("/me/statuses", "fields"=>"message")

    end
```

However, when I tried to loop through data using the following

Views/main/index.html.erb

```
<% if current_user %>

Looping through your statuses:<br />
<ul>

<% @graph_data.each do |status| %>
<%= status["message"] %> (<i><%=status["updated_time"]%></i>)<hr>
<% end %>
</ul>

  <% end %>
```

It didn't give me any status updates

Comment: Doesn't Devise provide `current_user`?  You should take that helper method out.

Comment: You also need to check if current_user is defined, or do `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in the controller.

Comment: @raphaelcm I updated the op. Once, I log in, I don't get that error :), however, I still can't pull the status updates. See op (if you can)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that current_user is returning nil.  This is probably because session[:user_id] is not set (ie user is not logged in).  You should have a check in index to protect against this:

```
def index
  if current_user
    @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(current_user.oauth_token)
  else
    # User isn't logged in; do something else
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not using devise. Is there a way to do this using the helper method?

Comment: Sorry - that's what I get for assuming.  Devise and OmniAuth are a nice combo: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Comment: Thanks, I got rid of the error, but I included another line from the Koala documentation to pull status updates. However, they're not showing in the views/main/index.html.erb

Comment: If it's not throwing an error, then it's just not getting any status updates.  You're either using the wrong parameters or the user doesn't have any status updates.

Comment: Also, that's a separate question from what you originally posted :)

Comment: true it is another question. however, just to continue, that same code  worked in a koala sample app that I cloned, and it pulled my status updates. However, when I integrated koala into this rails cast app, it's not getting status updates.

Comment: ok, got it, didn't get the permissions in this new app for that.